# sql double records in simple search

Tags: sql, duplicates, union

I'm making a simple forum search for my site, which pulls data from 2 tables.

```
SELECT ft.id, ft.title, ft.date 
  FROM forum_topics ft 
  WHERE ft.title LIKE '%" .$search. "%' OR ft.body LIKE '%" .$search. "%' 
UNION SELECT fr.topic, ft.title, fr.date 
  FROM forum_replies fr 
    INNER JOIN forum_topics ft ON fr.topic=ft.id 
  WHERE fr.body LIKE '%" .$search. "%' 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

It's pulling duplicates if it finds the term in both tables, how can I make it so it wont show duplicate records if the `id` of the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try wrapping the `UNION` in another select, and add a `GROUP BY` on all columns:

```
SELECT g.id, g.title, g.date
FROM (
    SELECT ft.id, ft.title, ft.date 
    FROM forum_topics ft 
    WHERE ft.title LIKE '%" .$search. "%' OR ft.body LIKE '%" .$search. "%' 
    UNION
    SELECT fr.topic as id, ft.title, fr.date 
    FROM forum_replies fr 
    INNER JOIN forum_topics ft ON fr.topic=ft.id 
    WHERE fr.body LIKE '%" .$search. "%' 
) g
GROUP BY g.id, g.title, g.date
ORDER BY g.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a SELECT DISTINCT id, title, date FROM (query above).

Alternately, you could add a line to the WHERE clause of select-from-ft that its id does not exist in fr.